# If India imposes similar measures as the USA against China, what would be China's options?

Tags: economy, china, india

India is a huge market for Chinese products. Recently, India imposed bans on 59 Chinese mobile apps. Even though Chinese investments are deeply entrenched in India, India is [mulling on restricting the economic activities of China.](https://www.wsj.com/articles/indias-retaliation-against-china-carries-economic-costs-11593869295)

If India adopts similar measures as the USA:

1. What would be China's options for retaliation?
2. How can China manage economic damage or can it?

**Note:** I am not going into if India can or cannot impose similar measures as the USA against China. I know, India can't immediately do that. But, given enough time and determination, any country can do anything.

Comment: I wonder which are the extremely essential imports from China to India

Comment: @SeverusSnape, pharma raw material, electronics.